# Error installing/uninstalling GeoMedia WebMap Professional_6 on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: windows-7, installation, .net-framework

On installing GeoMedia `WebMap Professional_06.01.03.08` on `Windows 7 Professional 64 bit`. Following Error window pop up at the end of installation process or if I uninstall it.

[image]

I have .Net framework 2, 3.5 and 4 installed.

---

### GeoMedia WebMap Professional Readme:

---

**System Requirements**

Installation Requirements

For Server-side **Microsoft .NET programming and running Version 2.0 or later** of the GeoMedia WebMap Professional .NET components and Services, it is required to have preinstalled the **Microsoft .NET Framework Version**. The installation uses utilities (regasm.exe) of this Framework version to register at installation the WebMap-related Primary Interop and Managed Code Assemblies.

**GeoMedia WebMap Professional Server-side Hardware**

GeoMedia WebMap Professional is designed to run on Intel chip-based server hardware/systems. Database hardware is not limited to Intel-based systems.

Response time is an important consideration for any web installation, so you should design your site to deliver the best possible performance for the environment in which you intend to publish information. If the number of WebMap Map Server executable instances (each serving a large number of concurrent user requests) is likely to be greater than 12, you should consider installing multi-processor servers.

**Requirements**

- Pentium III or equivalent microprocessor -- minimum
- 300 MB disk space required for Typical installation
- Up to 1 GB disk space (2 GB or greater recommended) to accommodate
  temporary cache files in a production environment
- 2 GB RAM or greater recommended, 100 MB RAM per map server minimum
- 128 KB ISDN or better communications connectivity

**Server-Side Software:**

**GeoMedia WebMap Professional supports the following software platforms:**

**Operating Systems:**

- Microsoft Windows Server 2003, 32-bit and 64-bit running in 32-bit
  emulation mode
- Microsoft Windows 2000 Server
- Microsoft Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 2 recommended)
- Microsoft Windows Vista, 32-bit and 64-bit running in 32-bit
  emulation mode

**Web Server Software:**

- IIS 7.0 for Windows Vista
- IIS 6.0 for Windows Server 2003
- IIS 5.0 for Windows XP Professional
- IBM HTTP Server (servlet engine of IBM Websphere or TomCat)
- Java via Intrinsyc's J-Integra® COM/Java bridge
- Oracle iAS (native servlet engine)
- Java via Intrinsyc's J-Integra COM/Java bridge
- Sun Open Net Environment Web Server (native servlet engine) (formerly
  Sun IPlanet)
- Sun Open Net Environment (Sun ONE) Active Server Pages (formerly Sun
  Chili!Soft ASP)
- Java via Intrinsyc's J-Integra COM/Java bridge

GeoMedia WebMap Professional works with any database that can be accessed with 32-bit ODBC drivers.

**.NET**

For Server-side Microsoft .NET programming and running of the GeoMedia WebMap Professional .NET components and Services, Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 or later, with ASP.NET. For programming, a .NET-supported Development Environment compatible with the Framework.

**GeoMedia WebMap Professional Client-side Software Requirements**

Operating System:

- Microsoft Windows XP
- Microsoft Windows Vista

**System Configuration**

**Microsoft .NET Framework**

GeoMedia WebMap Professional 6.1 requires the Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0.  GeoMedia WebMap Professional 6.1 was certified against .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.0.

- Windows XP .NET 2.0.
- Windows Vista .NET 3.0 (includes 2.0).

**Loading GeoMedia WebMap Professional on a 64-bit Operating System**

This section provides the system administrator and end user with information on installing and deploying GeoMedia WebMap Professional on a 64-bit operating system.  If you run on a 64-bit operating system, such as Windows Vista™ x64, you will need to know the differences discussed in this section.  GeoMedia WebMap Professional is a 32-bit application, but it can be run on most 64-bit processors.  Loading GeoMedia WebMap Professional on a 64-bit operating system will result in a few changes in folder and license file locations, registry entries, and use of Microsoft Windows tools.

Folder Location—Folder structures for GeoMedia WebMap Professional are different on 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems.  On a 32-bit operating system, all GeoMedia WebMap Professional folders and Common Files folders install under C:\Program Files.  On a 64-bit operating system, these folders install under C:\Program Files (x86).

License Files—When placing a license file for GeoMedia WebMap Professional on a 64-bit operating system, it must be placed in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intergraph\Ingr_Licenses.  Note there is no Intergraph folder in C:\Program Files\Common Files on a 64-bit operating system.  Like the license folder, GeoMedia WebMap will be placed in C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoMedia WebMap Professional.

Registry Entries—In a similar fashion, GeoMedia WebMap Professional and related registry entries are different on a 64-bit operating system.  GeoMedia WebMap Professional HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry entries are unchanged on a 64-bit system, but HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry entries are in a different location.  The new location for local machine entries for GeoMedia WebMap Professional on a 64-bit operating system is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Wow6432Node > Intergraph.  If the FlexLM entry for GeoMedia WebMap Professional licensing needs to be modified for license file location or concurrent license server reference, it is also in the new location at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Wow6432Node > FlexLM license manager.

32-bit Compatible Applications—Any 32-bit compatible operating system application used in conjunction with GeoMedia WebMap Professional has also been relocated on a 64-bit operating system.  For example, ODBCad32.exe is the application used to create ODBC DSNs that may be used for various GeoMedia warehouse connections.  There are two different ODBCad32.exe files on a 64-bit Windows operating system.  One normally resides in C:\Windows\System32, the other in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  Because a 64-bit operating system can run both 32-bit and 64-bit applications, a folder is used to distinguish 32-bit applications from 64-bit applications.  Windows applications available from Windows Explorer views reference 64-bit applications.  If you need to run a 32-bit Windows application, you must browse to the 32-bit folder, and then run the application from there.  The 32-bit Windows applications will be found in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  The 64-bit applications will be found in C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: Have you checked the readme file for ".Net System Requirements"? What does it say?

Comment: Can you post the readme for our reference? Also note the there are two types of .NET installs (Starting from .NET 3.5). One is a client only install and another is a FULL install that contains both client and server version of .NET Framework. The version of .NET that comes by default in Windows 7 is .NET 3.5 client. And Windows update only installs the client version of .NET 4. The fulle version of .NET 4 can be found at:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: I have installed VS 2010 and I think VS 2010 install full version of .Net Framework 4.

Comment: Is the Package a `msi` or `exe` ?

Comment: @Akshat It is exe

Comment: You should Try Installing the .NET framework Again (as maybe some components can get damaged over time).

Comment: Can you try to Extract *.msi package from exe file (as some exe installers have a msi package embed in them or similar).

Comment: @Akshat We in team had tried installing it on 3 different machines. One having Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit and other two has Windows Professional 7 64 bit and same error on all three machines. One of the Windows 7 Professional had fresh installation. I think it is unlikely that all three machines has damaged components but I will give it a try to check this. Thanks for sparing your time and giving suggestions to solve my issue. I am so greatfull.

Comment: The readme you posted suggests that only Windows Vista is supported. Can you run the setup.exe with Compatibility Mode set to Windows Vista SP2? The error you are getting seems to be because its not able to find regasm (.NET 2)

Comment: Also Visual Studio 2010 only installs .NET 4.0 not 2 or 3.5. 2 is shipped by default with Win 7 and 3.5 is a feature that needs to be enabled in Control Panel/

Comment: Can you please post the log file of the installation if it exists?

Comment: @Ganesh I have already tried it in compatibility mode Vista SP2 and Windows XP but all in vain. And you said that 4 is installed with .Net 4 then is is installed and I have double checked and 2 and 3.5 are both installed and enabled.

Comment: @Akshat Where can I find log file? I have checked in %temp% folder but there is no log file for this installation.

Comment: Try `%appdata%` or `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local` , These directories can contain the log file also I am gonna give you an app built by me (that app is nothing but a test for multiple things). Tell me the output of the app, if this is OK for you, then tell me your E-mail ID.